# Check field and rewrite to array Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to truncate string and rewrite it back to array

I have got a function where I get data from data base

```
 $data['about_text_list'] = $this->about_text_model->get_array();
```

I get these fields from data base : id, num, header, text, language

I need to strip_tags and truncate text with function word_limiter

```
        foreach ($data['about_text_list'] as $items)
        {
            $data['about_text_list']['text'] = word_limiter($items['text'], 100);

            $data['about_text_list']['text'] = strip_tags($items['text']);
        }
```

in view I do foreach

```
<? foreach ($about_text_list as $line) : ?>

    <td><?=$line['text']?></td>

<? endforeach; ?>
```

But I get error, please tell me how to do correct things like this...

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Can I assume the function calls in the foreach loop are only example code? You are rewriting the same field in each line.

Comment: no errors ... displaying results in view text is full not 100 and all images , youtube video display ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the loop in your controller, you're limiting the word count, then setting that to the value in the array. Then, you're overwriting that value with the `strip_tags` function. You're using both functions on the same value instead of using the altered values. (And I would strip the tags first, then limit the word count.)

You're also just overwriting the `$data['about_text_list']['text']` value each iteration. I'm assuming this needs to be an array of 'text' values? I would create a new array with the updated content and merge your `$data['about_text_list']` array with the new array.

Change that loop to this:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($data['about_text_list'] as $key => $value)
{
    $item_text = $value['text'];
    $altered = strip_tags($item_text);
    $newarray[$key]['text'] = word_limiter($altered, 100);
}
$data['about_text_list'] = array_merge($data['about_text_list'], $newarray);

// here, you create a new empty array,
// then loop through the array getting key and value of each item
// then cache the 'text' value in a variable
// then strip the tags from the text key in that item
// then create a new array that mirrors the original array and set 
//   that to the limited word count
// then, after the loop is finished, merge the original and altered arrays
//   the altered array values will override the original values
```

Also, I'm not sure what your error is (as you haven't told us), but make sure you're loading the text helper to give you access to the `word_limiter` function:

```
$this->load->helper('text');
```

**Of course, this all depends on the structure of your array, which I'm guessing at right now.**